# ngClass does not apply all classes in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using ngClass to change my icon color using this code:

```
<button
                type="button"
                [ngClass]="{'btn btn-sm btn-round btn-icon btn-outline-info':item.exitPlaza, 'btn btn-sm btn-round btn-icon btn-outline-warning':!item.exitPlaza}"
                ngbTooltip="{{hasPayment(item.exitPlaza)}}"
                [closeDelay]="500"
                (click)="openXl(content); setVehicleHistory(item)"
              >
```

The color changes alright but not all the classes are rendered. if there is `item.exitPlaza`, the button class is only `btn-outline-info` the `btn btn-sm btn-round` is not included on inspect element, but if `!item.exitPlaza` then all classess are included so I get the right design.

Comment: Again, please try to refrain from begging on this platform. Keep your questions succinct and free of clutter. Technical writing is preferred here.

Comment: @halfer, I am not 'BEGGING'. Just because I said 'PLEASE' doesn't mean I am begging. If I ask a direction; 'Could you please show me the way to the grocery. I'm kinda lost?' Is that begging already for you?

Comment: In real life, no. That is because pleasantries and politenesses are normal in informal, everyday conversations. But here, technical writing is an expectation, and politenesses do not belong in technical writing. It goes without saying that wiki authors do not say "Hello" at the start of their articles, and journalists do not finish a piece with "Hope that helps".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A, and thus can be thought of as being like documentation. Here, we are writing **more for future readers than for ourselves**, even though getting a useful answer is a nice side-effect. Thus, succinctness is valued - mainly because it helps future readers if material is straight to the point.

Comment: It is for this reason that editors will try to remove greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc.

Comment: Furthermore, it should be noted that editors (and other curators such as close voters) are volunteers on this platform. There are not enough of us to cope with the vast stream of woeful illiteracy and plz-do-my-homework material we get here. Thus, given that your question history must have been edited some 50+ times now, I would ask you to have mercy on us. We are trying to keep things tidy here, even if that is a fool's errand - and it is especially dispiriting if someone is giving us more work to do deliberately.

Answer (score 1):

Try to only assign classes which are actually different for those cases:

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-icon"
  [ngClass]="{'btn-outline-info': item.exitPlaza, 'btn-outline-warning': !item.exitPlaza}"
  ngbTooltip="{{hasPayment(item.exitPlaza)}}"
  [closeDelay]="500"
  (click)="openXl(content); setVehicleHistory(item)"
>
```

You can combine `class` attribute with `[ngClass]` and it makes code readable and you're always sure that the default styling is there

Comment: I tried this Sir but it didn't work for me. So I just made this. => [ngClass]="!item.exitPlaza ? 'btn btn-sm btn-round btn-icon btn-outline-danger' : 'btn btn-sm btn-round btn-icon btn-outline-info'". Thank you for the insight though. Ill just add a point since this didn't solve my issue..